# How do I add a file to an Android project and then load it using the NDK

Tags: android, c++, file-io, android-ndk

I am using the latest version of Android Studio (2.2.3) and I have loaded up the HelloGL2 sample project.

I now want to add a file (any type of file) to my app, and then be able to open it and read it in the c++ code using something like c's fopen etc (any direct file access api is fine)

How do I do this?

Comment: Use [`Asset`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___asset.html) or pass an absolute path to a file via JNI call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two options,  it will depend on your target.
 If your file is a basic text configuration file, you can use both cases, but if your file is a 3D object such as (.obj, .max, .dae) you should use **AssetManager** class.

**First option: (store your files in res raw (You can use fopen())).**

- Create a folder called **raw** inside res directory (res->raw).
- Write your files in the apk private directory.

In Java:

```
    public void writeFileToPrivateStorage(int fromFile, String toFile) 
    {

       InputStream is =   mContext.getResources().openRawResource(fromFile);
       int bytes_read;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];  
         try 
         {
            FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput(toFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            while ((bytes_read = is.read(buffer)) != -1)            
                fos.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read); // write

            fos.close();
            is.close();

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
         catch (IOException e) 
         {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                 
    }
```

Then, call to your function:

```
        writeFileToPrivateStorage(R.raw.your_file,"your_output_file.txt");
```

- Get your private path

```
    path=mContext.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString();
```

- Define your JNI funcion in Java:

```
    public static native void setconfiguration(String yourpath);
```

- Implement it in C/C++:

```
     JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_setconfiguration(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring path)
        {
            //convert your string into std::string. 
            const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(config_path, 0);
            //make here your fopen.
            fopen(nativeString,"r");
        }
```

**Second option (use assetManager, usually for opengl resources).**

The parameter, in this case, is not the path of the directory is the asset manager.

- Store your files in the asset directory.
- Define your native function in C/C++

```
     public static native void yourfunction(AssetManager assetManager);
```

- Call in java to this function:

```
     loadYourFile(m_context.getAssets());
```

- Create your jni function in C/C++

```
    JNIEXPORT void   Java_com_android_gl2jni_GL2JNILib_(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,jobject java_asset_manager)
        {
         AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env,java_asset_manager);
            AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, (const char *) js, AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
            if (NULL == asset) {
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, NF_LOG_TAG, "_ASSET_NOT_FOUND_");
                return JNI_FALSE;
            }
            long size = AAsset_getLength(asset);
            char* buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*size);
            AAsset_read (asset,buffer,size);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, NF_LOG_TAG, buffer);
            AAsset_close(asset);
        }
```

Note: Do not forget to add the permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Note II: Do not forget to add:

```
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>
```

I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! was so hard to find a clear example on this.
Just wondering, is it bad form to keep the mgr pointer and use it later? so just pass the asset manager to the native code once and then use that pointer to load assets during the lifetime of the app in the native code?

Comment: you are right @matt, it is not bad idea to keep the mgr pointer, I usually use the setterFunction like setAssetManager() to keep in my opengl resource loader classes.

Comment: One more thing, if your final target is to load 3D objects, use assimp 3D library http://www.assimp.org/. Cheers.

Comment: That library looks awesome!